# Did Israel return to Mount Hor after destroying the king of Arad in the Negev in Numbers 21?

Tags: numbers, moses

It is said they set out of Kadesh and came to Mount Hor were Aaron died

Numbers 20:22 NLT

***22 The whole community of Israel left Kadesh and arrived at Mount Hor***. 23 There, on the border of the land of Edom, the Lord said to Moses and Aaron, 24 “The time has come for Aaron to join his ancestors in death. He will not enter the land I am giving the people of Israel, because the two of you rebelled against my instructions concerning the water at Meribah. 25 Now take Aaron and his son Eleazar up Mount Hor. 26 There you will remove Aaron’s priestly garments and put them on Eleazar, his son. Aaron will die there and join his ancestors.”

After this incident it is said Israel fought against the king of Arad who lived in the Negev and they defeated them.

Numbers 21:1-3 NLT

***The Canaanite king of Arad, who lived in the Negev, heard that the Israelites were approaching on the road through Atharim***. So he attacked the Israelites and took some of them as prisoners. 2 Then the people of Israel made this vow to the Lord: “If you will hand these people over to us, we will completely destroy[a] all their towns.” 3 The Lord heard the Israelites’ request and gave them victory over the Canaanites. The Israelites completely destroyed them and their towns, and the place has been called Hormah[b] ever since.

Then again it is said they left Mount Hor taking the road to the red sea

Numbers 21:4 NLT

***4 Then the people of Israel set out from Mount Hor***, taking the road to the Red Sea[c] to go around the land of Edom. But the people grew impatient with the long journey,

Did they bury Aaron at Mount Hor then went to the Negev and returned back to Mount Hor?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is made tricky because the exact location and identification of Mt Hor is debated and quite uncertain.  What we can know is the following:

- Aaron was buried atop Mt. Hor according to Num 20:28
- After morning Aaron's death for 30 days, the Israelites turned southward on their journey toward the Red Sea to travel to the south of Edom because passage through Edom had been denied.  They then turned eastward and travelled through "Arabah" and finally northward to approach the land east of the Jordan.

Thus, from the little that is recorded, Mt Hor appears to be west and near the border of Edom, and north of the Red Sea, but still outside Edom.

I see no evidence that Israel visited Mt Hor twice.